# How to validate a patch file for patch-package?

Tags: validation, patch-package

I have a made a patch file for patch-package npm module: https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

Problem is, when I try to run the patch, it results in this error:

> **ERROR** Failed to apply patch for package react-native
> This happened because the patch file patches/react-native+0.59.10.patch could not be parsed.

How can I validate and locate the error where the patch file parsing went wrong?

Patch-package version: "patch-package": "^6.4.5",